# Can someone please look my code for atm project?

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

Currently, I am working on a ATM project. I was able to make it work. However, I'm not sure what to do if the user enters an undercase letter than the uppercase letter on the switch statement. Also, should I use a while loop so the user can able to repeat the steps. Finally, I'm stuck on how to let the user exit the program whenever. Like for instance, exiting after completing their selection.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    double checkingAccount = 5000;
    double savingAccount = 2000;
    
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Welcoming the user! 
    
    System.out.println("=======================");
    System.out.println("Welcome to SoundBank!");
    System.out.println("=======================");
    
    // Selections for the user
    System.out.println("Please choose: \nA - Checking Account \nB - Savings Account");
    String choice1 = cin.nextLine();
     
    System.out.println("Please choose of the following: \nD - Deposit \nW - Withdrawal \nC - Check Balance \nE - Exit");
    String choice2 = cin.nextLine();
    
    // It's time for loops
    
    
    
    switch (choice2) {
        case "D": 
            
            // Checking Account
            if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                
                System.out.println("How much you do you want to deposit?");
                double amount = cin.nextDouble();
                double total1 = checkingAccount + amount;
                System.out.println("You deposited " + amount);
                System.out.println("You currently have: " + total1);
                
            } else
            
            // Saving Account 
            if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                
                System.out.println("How much you do you want to deposit?");
                double amount2 = cin.nextDouble();
                double total2 = savingAccount + amount2;
                System.out.println("You deposited " + amount2);
                System.out.println("You currently have: " + total2);
                
            }  
            
            break;

        case "W":
            
            // Checking Account 
            if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                System.out.println("How much do you want to withdraw?");
                double amount3 = cin.nextDouble();
                double total3 = checkingAccount - amount3;
                System.out.println("You withdrew " + amount3);
                System.out.println("You currently have: " + total3);
            } else 
            // Saving Account
            if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) { 
                System.out.println("How much do you want to withdraw?");
                double amount4 = cin.nextDouble();
                double total4 = savingAccount - amount4;
                System.out.println("You withdrew " + amount4);
                System.out.println("You currently have: " + total4);
            } 
            break;
            
        case "C":
            // Checking Account
            if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                System.out.println("Your current balance is: " + checkingAccount);
            } else 
            // Saving Account 
            if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                System.out.println("Your current balance is: " + savingAccount);
            }
            break;
        case "E":
            System.out.println("You exited the program.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please choose a selction.");
    } 
    
    
}
```

Comment: A simple way to deal with different case is to convert everything to uppercase `choice = choice.toUpperCase();`  (And it's "lowercase" not "undercase.")

Answer (score 4):

I would just do

```
switch(choice2.toUpperCase())
```

so you don't have to worry about whether they put in upper or lowercase, but you could also do

```
case "D": // fall through
case "d":
```

to have two cases for the same block of code.

For existing the program, since it is all in the `main` function, you can just return

```
 case "E":
     System.out.println("You exited the program.");
     return;
```